# How can I get all MySQL commands in the current PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

How can i get all the MySQL commands which has been already worked in the current php script?I'm not useing any frameworks, I tried to google, but clearly that I cann't get anything helpful, please give me some useful advices and forgiving my poor English, thanks you guys.

Comment: Do you use MySQLi or PDO?

Answer (score 0):

From linux command line:

`grep -n mysql_* [yourfile.php]`

Which will give you every instance of a mysql_ command (e.g. mysql_connect(), mysql_close(), etc) and the line number where it was found in the file. It may be useful to dump the output of this command into a file by doing the following:

`grep -n mysql_* [yourfile.php] > mysql_commands.txt`

Grep has a number of useful options for searching for a text string within a single file, a group of files, or an entire directory. Use `grep --help` to see some of these options.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP means the commands which are actually executed in the course of running a script, not all commands which can be found in the code. This would also leave out commands especially if Object Oriented Programming is used, and the code has lines such as `$stmt->execute()` or `$sql->query()`

Answer (score 0):

Without any framework, you need to make your own function to run any SQL on your page, eg:

```
$sql = 'select * from users limit 10';
$rows = run_sql($sql);
$sql = 'update users set male=1 where id=2';
$rows = run_sql($sql);
...

function run_sql($sql) {
    global $debug;
    if ($debug) {
        echo '<p>', htmlsepecialchars($sql), '</p>';
    }
    //do what you normally do with the SQL
}
```

Before php framework, there are lots of nice db functions you can get by asking google. Nowadays not much as many people move to frameworks.

If you want an example, have a look of Topnew DB Helper, it is a function: http://topnew.net/cms/wiki/cms_db.php